# Почему картинки в блоке с owl-carousel отображаются неверно?

Tags: html, css, owl-carousel

Как сделать так, чтобы картинки в блоке в галереей отображались по одной и при этом не растягивались? У меня они почему-то показываются все. Пробовал задавать owl-item=100%, но это не помогает.
PS нажимать надо на блок 'Маникюр'

код jsfiddle.net/eptdhbvr/

сайт tempeswo.beget.tech

//[image: введите сюда описание изображения]